# Some conditions for continuity of a real function

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let $f:S\to \mathbb{R}$ be strictly monotone where $S\subseteq \mathbb{R}$. If the one of following conditions holds

$f(S)$ is open or $f(S)$ is closed, or $f(S)$ is connected,

then $f$ is continuous.
Why?

Comment: How is $S$ defined?

Comment: $S\subseteq \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: That's right. How about  two other conditions?

Answer (score 1):

First off, we are going to state an important theorem relative to discontinuities of monotone functions. If I remember correctly, there is a proof in *Walter Rudin*'s book (the baby one).

> Monotone function only have jump or removable singularities.

Thus, if your function $f:S\to \mathbb{R}$ is discontinuous, it may only have these types of singularities. Let's suppose $f$ and discontinuous at a point $x\in S$. We will show that $f(S)$ is neither closed nor open and not connected. Thus, by contraposition, your statement will be true.

Suppose $x\in \mathrm{int}\; S$. Then, we have 
$$\lim_{y\to x^-} f(y)\leq f(x)\leq \lim_{y\to x^+} f(y)$$
If equality hold for one case (without any loss of generality $\lim_{y\to x^-} f(y)= f(x)$), then the image $f(S)$ is not closed nor open and disconnected. In fact, the complement of the region close to $f(x)$ looks like the interval $(a,b\rbrack$. If equality doesn't hold, then the region of $S$ near $f(x)$ is just a single point. The complement of $f(S)$ looks like $\lbrack a,b)\cup (b,c\rbrack$ in this region. You should fill in the details here.

If $x\not\in \mathrm{int}\; S$, again, you can do the same kind of reasonning with limits.

I think this shows the idea. I do not claim this to be a complete proof. The details should follow easily from here fortunately.

Comment: Why is f(S) clopen?

Comment: Sorry, I was mistaken. I corrected my statement. Proof is still the same.

Comment: Thanks so much...

Comment: If you do not understand the argument, I can clarify it. Is there any part of it which is unclear for you?

Comment: Thanks. Why does $f(S)$ look like $[a,b)\cup (b,c]$?